# Random markers and animation in Nutiteq 3D and OpenStreetMaps

Tags: android, openstreetmap, marker

I'm going to develop a location-based game for android platforms. I want to create a marker in  random coordinates (around the user location) but on the road! Moreover i'm going to animate this marker from this point (A) to second random point (B). Any idea?

thank you!

ps.I use the sample code of the example of Nutiteq 3D map app.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.nutiteq.MapView;
import com.nutiteq.components.Color;
import com.nutiteq.components.Components;
import com.nutiteq.components.MapPos;
import com.nutiteq.components.Options;
import com.nutiteq.geometry.Marker;
import com.nutiteq.log.Log;
import com.nutiteq.projections.EPSG3857;
import com.nutiteq.projections.Projection;
import com.nutiteq.rasterlayers.TMSMapLayer;
import com.nutiteq.style.MarkerStyle;
import com.nutiteq.ui.DefaultLabel;
import com.nutiteq.ui.Label;
import com.nutiteq.utils.UnscaledBitmapLoader;
import com.nutiteq.vectorlayers.MarkerLayer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MapView mapView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // enable logging for troubleshooting - optional
    Log.enableAll();
    Log.setTag("hellomap");

    // 1. Get the MapView from the Layout xml - mandatory
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    // Optional, but very useful: restore map state during device rotation,
    // it is saved in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() below
    Components retainObject = (Components) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (retainObject != null) {
        // just restore configuration and update listener, skip other initializations
        mapView.setComponents(retainObject);
        MyLocationMapEventListener mapListener = (MyLocationMapEventListener) mapView.getOptions().getMapListener();
        mapListener.reset(this, mapView);
        mapView.startMapping();
        return;
    } else {
        // 2. create and set MapView components - mandatory
        mapView.setComponents(new Components());
    }

    // 3. Define map layer for basemap - mandatory.
    // Here we use MapQuest open tiles
    // Almost all online tiled maps use EPSG3857 projection.
    TMSMapLayer mapLayer = new TMSMapLayer(new EPSG3857(), 0, 18, 0,
            "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/", "/", ".png");

    mapView.getLayers().setBaseLayer(mapLayer);

    // set initial map view camera - optional. "World view" is default
    // Location: San Francisco 
    // NB! it must be in base layer projection (EPSG3857), so we convert it from lat and long
    mapView.setFocusPoint(mapView.getLayers().getBaseLayer().getProjection().fromWgs84(-122.41666666667f, 37.76666666666f));
    // rotation - 0 = north-up
    mapView.setRotation(0f);
    // zoom - 0 = world, like on most web maps
    mapView.setZoom(10.0f);
    // tilt means perspective view. Default is 90 degrees for "normal" 2D map view, minimum allowed is 30 degrees.
    mapView.setTilt(75.0f);


    // Activate some mapview options to make it smoother - optional
    mapView.getOptions().setPreloading(true);
    mapView.getOptions().setSeamlessHorizontalPan(true);
    mapView.getOptions().setTileFading(true);
    mapView.getOptions().setKineticPanning(true);
    mapView.getOptions().setDoubleClickZoomIn(true);
    mapView.getOptions().setDualClickZoomOut(true);

    // set sky bitmap - optional, default - white
    mapView.getOptions().setSkyDrawMode(Options.DRAW_BITMAP);
    mapView.getOptions().setSkyOffset(4.86f);
    mapView.getOptions().setSkyBitmap(
            UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.sky_small));

    // Map background, visible if no map tiles loaded - optional, default - white
    mapView.getOptions().setBackgroundPlaneDrawMode(Options.DRAW_BITMAP);
    mapView.getOptions().setBackgroundPlaneBitmap(
            UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.background_plane));
    mapView.getOptions().setClearColor(Color.WHITE);

    // configure texture caching - optional, suggested 
    mapView.getOptions().setTextureMemoryCacheSize(40 * 1024 * 1024);
    mapView.getOptions().setCompressedMemoryCacheSize(8 * 1024 * 1024);

    // define online map persistent caching - optional, suggested. Default - no caching
    mapView.getOptions().setPersistentCachePath(this.getDatabasePath("mapcache").getPath());
    // set persistent raster cache limit to 100MB
    mapView.getOptions().setPersistentCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024);


    // 4. Start the map - mandatory
    mapView.startMapping();


    // 5. Add simple marker to map. 
    // define marker style (image, size, color)
    Bitmap pointMarker = UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.olmarker);
    MarkerStyle markerStyle = MarkerStyle.builder().setBitmap(pointMarker).setSize(0.5f).setColor(Color.WHITE).build();
    // define label what is shown when you click on marker
    Label markerLabel = new DefaultLabel("San Francisco", "Here is a marker");

    // define location of the marker, it must be converted to base map coordinate system
    MapPos markerLocation = mapLayer.getProjection().fromWgs84(-122.416667f, 37.766667f);

    // create layer and add object to the layer, finally add layer to the map. 
    // All overlay layers must be same projection as base layer, so we reuse it
    MarkerLayer markerLayer = new MarkerLayer(mapLayer.getProjection());
    markerLayer.add(new Marker(markerLocation, markerLabel, markerStyle, null));
    mapView.getLayers().addLayer(markerLayer);

    // add event listener
    MyLocationMapEventListener mapListener = new MyLocationMapEventListener(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOptions().setMapListener(mapListener);

    // add GPS My Location functionality 
    MyLocationCircle locationCircle = new MyLocationCircle();
    mapListener.setLocationCircle(locationCircle);
    initGps(locationCircle);
}

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    Log.debug("onRetainNonConfigurationInstance");
    return this.mapView.getComponents();
}

protected void initGps(final MyLocationCircle locationCircle) {
    final Projection proj = mapView.getLayers().getBaseLayer().getProjection();

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() 
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
             if (locationCircle != null) {
                 locationCircle.setLocation(proj, location);
                 locationCircle.setVisible(true);
                 mapView.setFocusPoint(mapView.getLayers().getBaseLayer().getProjection().fromWgs84(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()));
             }
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.debug("GPS onStatusChanged "+provider+" to "+status);
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.debug("GPS onProviderEnabled");
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.debug("GPS onProviderDisabled");
        }
    };

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 100, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);

}
```

ps.This is excactly i wand to do but in android sdk http://openplans.github.io/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker/

Answer (score 2):

You can just use setMapPos() method of Markers in Nutiteq SDK.